# Creating footnotes with Velocity and XDocReport in word

Tags: ms-word, velocity, xdocreport

I am trying to create dynamic footnotes with Velocity and XDocReport in a Word document, where the footnotes includes information from the data.

For example, if I include a footnote reference inside a foreach loop and then in the footnote itself I create a reference to a value, like $firstName, the footnotes are created and incremented appropriately.  But inside each footnote, the variable is simply outputted as $firstName, instead of being replaced by its value.

I have tried a work around, where in my loop I create another variable.  Like:

> ## foreach($firstName in $firstNames.values())
>
> ## set($footnoteName = $firstName) $footnoteName[FN]
>
> ## end
>
> ---
>
> [FN] $footnoteName

In that case, the value of the $footnoteName variable IS included in the footnote, but it's always the value of the LAST record in the collection, so every footnote gets the same values.

Edit:  The $velocityCount variable, when inserted into the footnote, DOES increment properly, so each footnote has a different value for that.

Comment: It seems that you have already posted at https://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/issues/detail?id=415 Footnotes are explained at https://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/wiki/DocxReportingJavaMainNotes but perhaps it should be improved?

Comment: Thanks. I did update that bug on the xdocreport site.  Hopefully you can help me figure it out.

Comment: I suspect that the footnotes are generated after the rest of the document. (I believe in the docx format, the footnotes are a separate xml file.)  It may be that the xdocreport does not have access to the value of each record when the footnotes are generated, only the value LAST given to a variable that is holding those values.

Comment: I "solved" this.  I created a hashmap variable before my loop for each variable I needed to reference in the footnote.  For example $fnValues.  Then inside the loop I inserted an item into the hashmap:  $velocityCount --> value.  Then inside the footnote, I grabbed that values with $fnValues.get($velocityCount).

Comment: Note that this solution only appears to work if EVERY record in the loop has a footnote generated, otherwise the data inserted into the footnote does not seem to match the data in the record being footnoted.  Perhaps there is another workaround.

Comment: I did manage to come up with a solution where every record does not have a footnote. You need to create a separate counter that tracks just the records that will have footnotes:

#set($fnValues={})
#set($fnCounter=0)

#foreach($record in $data)
   Here is some information: $record.FieldA
   #if($record.FieldB == "includeFN")
     #set($fnCounter=$fnCounter+1)
     $!{fnValues.put($fnCounter,$record.FieldC)}
     [FN]
   #end
#end

----
[FN] Here is some additional information:  $fnValues.get($velocityCount)